# How do I use a visual dataset's additional query as the dataSource/dataMember of a bindingSource?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, strongly-typed-dataset

How do I use an additional query (FillByQuery) within a visual DataSet as the dataSource/dataMember of a bindingSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional queries all load into exactly the same table in the dataset.  Each query can return approximately the same data, but use different tables and parameters.

dim ta as new myTableAdapter
dim md as new myDataSet
.
.
.
dim bs as new BindingSource
bs.Datamember="myTable"
bs.DataSource=myDataSet

ta.PrimaryQuery(md.myTable, parameter1, Parameter2)

ta.AlternateQuery(md.myTable, parameter3)

Note if you are doing this in the form designer, most of this is taken care of for you, when you drag a dataource onto a form.

All of the loaded records from both queries go straight into the table in the dataset.  You don't need to do anything special with your additional queries.

Comment: When using the form designer there is no way to select one of the queries attached to a table in a dataset for use in a bindingSource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the form designer.
I have an area on the form for adding new "ticket" records. This area has a combobox that lists only active "locations" and has an "Add" button that insert a new record.

I have a dataGridView that shows all "ticket" records with an embedded combobox of "Locations" so that the user can edit the value if needed. This combobox is using the same bindingSource as the "add new" "location" combobox. 
The dataset that the bindingSource is using has additional queries to show the complete list of "location" or just the active "locations".

The problem is that if the dataGridView is trying to show an old "Ticket" record with an inactive "location" the required record is not in the "location" dataset and causes an error. So, I was going to bind the dataGridView's "location" Combobox to a complete listing of "location" records. So next I thought this is going to allow users to edit records and unknowingly choose inactive "locations". My solution in the end was to change the original "location" dataset to have records append "(inactive)" onto their descriptions so users will know this "location" is inactive. I never implemented a second bindingSource.

Comment: You could also just add a filter to the binding source to 'hide' the inactive records, but check the raw table to ensure no duplicates.